# Is ok to import folder multiple times in Go?

Tags: go

Is it okay to import the same folder several times? I do it like this because the files of my routes are in that folder, and I add the identifier to know what route it is and then call the function.

Inside my routes folder I have(example purpose only):

```
routes_
   |_ route_1.go
   |_ route_2.go
   |_ route_3.go
```

Import example:

```
import(
    Route1 "./routes"
    Route2 "./routes"
    Route3 "./routes"
)

func main(){
    Route1.get()
    Route2.post()
    Route3.put()
}
```

Comment: "to know what route it is" --- why don't you give your functions meaningful names instead?

Comment: because I want to know from which file that function comes

Comment: A common way to deal with this situation is to use filenames that match function names

Comment: The thing is that one file has 4 functions, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE and some extra functions.

Comment: Given they all come from a single package, how importing it multiple times makes any difference?

Comment: Im just concern that is a bad way of doing things so thats why i ask  so i can do the things right ;P :'v

Comment: It is uncommon to import a package multiple times. It's also uncommon to use relative import paths. The best way to get more meaningful names in the importing package is to split the package into separate packages with meaningful names.

Comment: As it is impossible to "import a folder" it is not possible to import it twice. The main building block in Go is the _package_ a concept only coupled by convention and the go tool to a file system folder. In any case you have to understand the concept of a package, how they are  composed and how they are used.

Comment: You don't import folders _at all_ in Go. You import packages.

Comment: Doing what you're describing makes no sense. Since they're all the same package, `Route1.get()` is the same as `Route3.get()`. All this does is make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create cycle of import file that leads to error.

if the name of package of all Route 1,2,3 are same you don't need to import them . you can directly access get(),put()and post() with in same package files.